# need to find every X minutes between to hours

Tags: java, jodatime

I have two hours lets say 12:00 and 14:00 (the input will always be two hours of "whatever" day) second time will always be greater than first time. So the input is simple : two given times in a day.  I need to find every 30 minutes between those two times.

I need the following output (the ellapsed time between each output will always be 30 minutes in my case:

12:00
12:30
13:00
13:30
14:00
14:30

I am discovering jodatime but I am a bit confused with how the determine "startTime" and "end Time"

Comment: Well it looks like they should be `startTime` and `endTime` for one thing. But it's *very* unclear what your actual input is, if you don't know how to determine the start and end... Please edit your question for clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty easy, actually:

```
DateTime current = start;
while(true){
    System.out.println(current);
    current=current.plusMinutes(30);
    if(current.isAfter(stop))break;
}
```

Responding to comment:

to parse a String, you need a `DateTimeFormatter`. Here's one of several ways to acquire one:

```
private static final DateTimeFormatter DATE_TIME_FORMATTER = 
    DateTimeFormat.forPattern("HH:mm");
```

Now you can do:

```
DateTime startDate = DATE_TIME_FORMATTER.parseDateTime(startString);
```

Comment: Thanks for that but please excuse my confusion, how do I initialize start and stop, (I have a String which is 12:00 for example)